# Mysterious Redis C core dump

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, redis

I am currently running a C program calling a Redis Server instance. After the 1020th iteration, it always bombs with:

> Redis Connect 1021 Error: System error Segmentation fault (core
>   dumped)

Ugh. Something tells me one of the pointers decided to go wild. Can anyone help here? I am using the current version of Ubuntu Linux

```
//codingsteps.com/installing-using-hiredis-c-client-library-for-redis/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "hiredis.h"

void redisTest(void) {
    redisReply *reply;
    long int i;

//      Start measuring time
    clock_t start = clock();

//      For local connections:
    //redisContext *c = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    redisContext *c = redisConnect("localhost", 6379);
//      For connections to a remote Redis server:
    //redisContext *c = redisConnect
          //       ("ec2-**-**-***-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com", 6379);
    if (c->err) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        }else{
            printf("Connection Made! \n");
        }
//  Get all keys for testing


    //reply = redisCommand(c, "keys %s", "*");
    reply = redisCommand(c, "lrange EUR 0 10", "*");    
    if ( reply->type == REDIS_REPLY_ERROR )
        printf( "Error: %s\n", reply->str );
    else if ( reply->type != REDIS_REPLY_ARRAY )
        printf( "Unexpected type: %d\n", reply->type );
    else {
        for ( i=0; i<reply->elements; ++i ){
               printf( "Result:%lu: %s\n", i,
                      reply->element[i]->str );
        }
    }
    printf( "Total Number of Results: %lu\n", i );

//      Output Elapsed time
        printf ( "%f Seconds\n", ( (double)clock() - start ) /
                      CLOCKS_PER_SEC );

    redisFree(c);
    freeReplyObject(reply);
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0; 
    for(;;) {
        printf("\n\nRedis Connect %d\n",i++);
        redisTest();

    }
}
```

Update: I added `redisFree()` as suggested by others (thanks for that). This still core dumps but after 28233 iterations.

Comment: Debugger didn't help? valgrind didn't help?

Comment: Why does it look like you are leaving 1020 connections open? That shouldn't lead to a core dump but still ...

Comment: So 3 file descriptors for stdin, stdout, stderr, and 1021 dangling file descriptors that should have been closed leaves you with no more file descriptors on a machine with a process limit of 1024 open fd's.

Comment: when the 'c->err' indicates an error occurred, then do NOT continue executing the program.  Rather cleanup and exit

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. I added redisFree() as hinted above

Comment: And now you also need to release the reply. freeReplyObject(reply)